# IF Else Error in Android application

Tags: android, if-statement

This if-else statement I am using it onClick method of Android code.

```
                if (input == null){

                    dispError();

                }else{

                    startAct();
                }
```

when value is true or false startAct() gets implemented;

```
                if (input != null){

                    dispError();

                }else{

                    startAct();
                }
```

when value is true or false dispError() gets implemented;
input is a string.

actual code of my program:
@Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

```
                // Launching Display Meaning Activity

                meaning = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

                input = meaning.getText().toString(); 


                if (input == null){

                    dispError();

                }else{

                    startAct();
                }

                }
            public void startAct(){

                Intent intent =new Intent("com.dictionary.khasi_english.DisplayMeaningActivity");

                intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, DisplayMeaningActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra(MEANING_INPUT, input);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
            public void dispError(){

                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("ERROR");
                        builder.setMessage("Please enter a Word.")  
                               .setCancelable(false)
                               .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                   }
                               });                     
                        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                        alert.show();               
                   }
                });
            }

        });
}
```

}

Comment: ...so what's the question?

Comment: Taking the first if-else statement; if input==null was true dispError() should have been implemented but instead startAct() gets implemented. And the same goes for the second if-else statement.

Comment: Why don't you use a boolean instead of string?

Comment: Because the input is actually taking the string value from the editText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`meaning.getText().toString()` will never return null. However, it can return `""`, an empty string. Use the following code to check against that:

```
if(input.isEmpty()) {
    dispError();
else {
    startAct();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because input, as you said, could be 'true' or 'false'. In both cases input is not null. If you want your if-statement works, you should try:

```
if(input.equals("true")) {
    startAct();
else {
    dispError();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to check whether the user put in any text, you should use [TextUtils.isEmpty](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29), which checks against both null and empty strings:

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(input)) {
    dispError();
} else {
    startAct();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if input is a string 
try to use input.length  to check if it is empty

`if(input.length==0)
    displayerror();`

because if `input=""`then it is not null.

you can use TextUtils.isEmpty()